# how to use onlyGovernance modifier?

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, inheritance, governance

I want to use [onlyGovernance](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/governance#Governor-onlyGovernance--) modifier in my contracts. I have a governance contract but I want to use this modifier that is not a governance contract. I want to use it so I can restrict some of my functions so that they can be only executable through governance proposals. Is there any other way to do this and any idea how can I use the `onlyGovernance` modifier properly?